# Return row number in QAbstractTableModel headerData

Tags: qt, qabstracttablemodel

I am using QTableView and QAbstractTableModel.
Can I get ordered row numbers in vertical header even after filtering and sorting?

Comment: Please post code, how do you sorting?

Comment: Just try to use any QSortFilterProxyModel and get 
ordered continuous row numbers

Answer (score 0):

Solution is reimplemented headerData in MySortFilterProxyModel:

```
QVariant MySortFilterProxyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole && orientation == Qt::Vertical)
        return section + 1;
    else
        return sourceModel()->headerData(section, orientation, role);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this is enough:

```
    QVariant MySortFilterProxyModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {

    return sourceModel()->headerData(section, orientation, role);
}
```

you can refer the Qt doc [here](http://www.walletfox.com/course/qsortfilterproxymodelexample.php)